# Bash variables do not expand inside array if declare is used

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl, array, readonly

Recently I decided to read a bit more on the bash built-ins `declare`, `local`, and `readonly`, which led me to switch from:

```
local variable_name
variable_name='value'
readonly variable_name
```

To:

```
variable_name='value'
declare -r variable_name
```

This change cut down the number of lines written and allowed me to set a few attributes, like telling bash that the value of a variable is an integer, which was nice. However, while creating a function that will serve as an alias for cURL, I noticed that variables inside an array never expand if I use `declare`, but expand just fine with `local` and `readonly`.

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit -o errtrace -o pipefail -o nounset
IFS=$'\n\t'

curl() {

  curl_version="$(command curl --version | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}')"
  declare -r curl_version

  curl_args=(
    --user-agent "curl/${curl_version}"
    --silent
    --fail
  )

  command curl "${curl_args[@]}" \
    "${@}"

}

curl --url 'https://httpbin.org/get'
```

Because the variables do not expand for whatever reason, the `--user-agent` part of the array makes the script exit with an error, since as far as bash knows, this is an unbound variable, and those are not allowed because of `set -o nounset`.

I have been trying to get this to work for a few days now, so I guess it is time to throw the towel and ask for help. Can anyone point me in the right direction to understand what I am doing wrong, please?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention, but the variable does expand if I declare it in the same line, like `declare -r variable_name`. The problem is, if I do that, I hit [SC2155 from ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155), hence why I am trying to declare after the value is set.

Comment: There's too much unnecessary code to read through. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) over on stackoverflow.

Comment: @glennjackman Fixed, thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Why do you think this is specific to arrays? Did you try simply doing `echo $curl_version;` there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With:

> ```
> curl_version="$(command curl --version | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}')"
> declare -r curl_version
> ```

within a function, you're setting the `$curl_version` global variable to some value and then creating a separate local and readonly variable which is initially unset.

It looks like you want:

```
# instantiate a new local variable (but in bash it inherits the "export"
# attribute if any of the variable with same name in the parent scope)
local curl_version

# unset to remove that export attribute if any. Though you could
# also change the above to local +x curl_version
unset -v curl_version

# give a value:
curl_version="$(command curl --version | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}')"

# make that local variable read only
local -r curl_version
```

(here using `local` instead of `declare` to make it clearer that you want to make the variable local¹).

Or do all at the same time with:

```
local +x -r curl_version="$(command curl --version | awk '{print $2; exit}')"
```

(though as noted by shellcheck, you then lose the exit status of the pipeline²).

In any case, I wouldn't use `readonly` / `typeset -r` in shells like you would use `const` in C especially in `bash`. Shells (other than ksh93) don't have static scoping like in C. And in `bash` (contrary to `zsh` for instance), you can't create a variable local to a function if it has been made readonly in the global scope.

For instance:

```
count() {
  local n
  for (( n = 0; n < $1; n++ )) { echo "$n"; }
}

readonly n=5
count "$n"
```

would work in zsh but not in bash. It may be OK if you only use `local -r` and never `readonly`.

---

<sup>¹ in any case `typeset` / `declare` / `local` are all the same in `bash`, the only difference being that if you try to use `local` outside of a function, it reports an error. The difference between `typeset -r` and `readonly` (same as between `typeset -x` and `export`) being that the latter doesn't instantiate a new variable if called within a function.</sup>

<sup>² See how with that `exit` in `awk` in that version for `awk` to stop processing the input after the first line, `curl` could be killed with a SIGPIPE (very unlikely in practice as `curl` would send its output in one go and it would fit in the pipe) and because of `pipefail`, the pipeline could end up failing with 141 exit status, but `local` itself would still succeed as long as it can assign a value to the variable.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! As I mentioned above, it seems like my understanding of `declare` was incorrect—it is always something obvious, isn't it?. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 7):

The first line of the function creates a **global** variable.

```bsh
  curl_version="$(command curl --version | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}')"
```

The second line of the function creates a **readonly, empty, LOCAL** variable

```bsh
  declare -r curl_version
```

This local variable overrides the value of the global variable.

Note this exerpt from `help declare`:

> When used in a function, `declare' makes NAMEs local, as with the `local'
> command.  The `-g' option suppresses this behavior.

I'd recommend this:

```bsh
curl() {

  local -r curl_version="$(command curl --version | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}')"

  local curl_args=(
    --user-agent "curl/${curl_version}"
    --silent
    --fail
  )

  command curl "${curl_args[@]}" \
    "${@}"
}
```

For inspecting the variables, add `declare -p curl_version curl_args` into the function before the command call.

Comment: My understanding of `declare` was incorrect, then. From `help declare`, I got the impression that it worked like `local`, while also setting attributes. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @JamesPond, it does work like `local` which is the point here.